# Formatting only headers with data using xlsxwriter

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

I'm having a little trouble getting the formatting by using `worksheet.set_row()` to apply only to columns with data. As it stands, when I open the workbook, the formatting gets applied to the entire header row, even past where the data stops and this looks a bit sloppy, see below:

[image]

As you can see, the formatting continues onto columns AL, AM, AN, AO, etc... Since there is no data in these columns (or headers for that matter) it looks a bit sloppy.

I was previously using the following to apply formatting to each sheet in my workbook:

```
header = workbook.add_format({'bold': True, 'bottom': 2, 'bg_color': '#F9DA04'})
worksheet.set_row(0, None, header)
```

I understand this is because `worksheet.set_row()` uses the row index. I can't find any documentation about this taking a range, could I somehow specify `A1:AK1` or something like that? If it matters, each worksheet is the result of a `pd.concat()` of multiple dataframes using Pandas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> As you can see, the formatting continues onto columns AL, AM, AN, AO, etc..

That is how row formatting works in Excel. If you apply it to a row then all cells are formatted.

> could I somehow specify A1:AK1 or something like that?

If you only want to format certain cells then it is best to apply the format just to those cells. For example:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

header_data = ['EID', 'Notification', 'Test #']

header_format = workbook.add_format({'bold': True,
                                     'bottom': 2,
                                     'bg_color': '#F9DA04'})

for col_num, data in enumerate(header_data):
    worksheet.write(0, col_num, data, header_format)

workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]

> If it matters, each worksheet is the result of a pd.concat() of multiple dataframes using Pandas.

For an example of how to format header from a dataframe see this example from the XlsxWriter [docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html#formatting-of-the-dataframe-headers):

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a Pandas dataframe from the data.
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data1': [10, 20, 30, 20],
                   'Data2': [10, 20, 30, 20],
                   'Data3': [10, 20, 30, 20],
                   'Data4': [10, 20, 30, 20]})

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Turn off the default header and skip one row to allow us to insert a
# user defined header.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=1, header=False)

# Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

# Add a header format.
header_format = workbook.add_format({'bold': True,
                                     'bottom': 2,
                                     'bg_color': '#F9DA04'})

# Write the column headers with the defined format.
for col_num, value in enumerate(df.columns.values):
    worksheet.write(0, col_num + 1, value, header_format)

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

Output:

[image]